# Need to know the right syntax of a count query to count rows by id

Tags: java, mysql, spring, count

I got these two tables and I want to have a query to count the amount of cars by each brand and insert this count to a column in the brand table
I've tried many queries but can't get it right.

First table,

[image]

Second table,

[image]

Comment: Are you after a SQL answer or a JPA answer?

Comment: Im using thymeleaf and want to make a chart with the count of cars by brands. So im looking for a sql answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `JOIN`.

**Query**

```
select t1.car_brand_id, t2.brand_name, count(t1.car_name) as total_count
from table1 t1
join table2 t2
on t1.car_brand_id = t2.brand_id
group by t1.car_brand_id, t2.brand_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need join  count and group by

this is a select   for see the count by brand_name

```
select b.brand_name, count(*) 
from table_one a 
inner join table_two b on b.brand_id = a.brand_id 
group by b.brand_name
```

Once you have added  the column you need  in table_two ( with  eg alter table command  adding my_count_col)

you could use an update like this

```
update table_two
inner join (
 select b.brand_name, count(*)  my_count
     from table_one a 
     inner join table_two b on b.brand_id = a.brand_id 
     group by b.brand_name ) t on t.brand_name  = table_two.brand_name
set table_two.my_count_col = t.my_count
```